# Ninject Make sure that the controller has a parameterless constructor with Owin and Web Api only after site restart

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

I have an app that always fails to initialize controllers just the first time. It only happens after the site has been restarted in IIS. After getting a 500 back from the app I can reload the page and everything works fine after that.

Haven't been able to find a similar scenario via google or SO.

I'm using quite a few nuget packages, they are

- Ninject
- Ninject.Web.Common
- Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost
- Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost
- Ninject.Web.WebApi
- Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost

This is the class that does configuration

```
    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyNameSpace.MyClass))]

    namespace MyNameSpace
    {
        internal class MyClass
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

                var config = new HttpConfiguration();
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                var kernel = CreateKernel();
                app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel);
                app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);

                config.EnsureInitialized();
            }

            private IKernel CreateKernel()
            {
                var kernel = new StandardKernel();
                kernel.Settings.InjectNonPublic = true;
                kernel.Bind<IMyDependency>().To<MyDependency>().InSingletonScope();
                // bindings
                return kernel;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's what the stack trace looks like if that helps

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> System.ArgumentException: Type 'MyController' does not have a default constructor
            at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
            at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
            at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
            at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
            at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

What could cause the app to fail the first time but work subsequently? Any help would be greatly appreciated

edit: controller code looks like

```
    public class MyController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly MyDependency _dependency;

        internal PathDeviationReportingController(MyDependency dependency)
        {
            _dependency = dependency;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Do Something
        /// </summary>
        /// <response code="200"></response>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("route/dosomething")]
        [SwaggerResponse(200)]
        public IHttpActionResult DoSomething()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

I since removed Ninject.Common.WebHost and this hasn't changed anything. still have the issue.

edited to update what the binding code actually looked like*

Comment: Could you post the code of `PathDeviationReportingController`?

Comment: controller code hase been added, spot anything that might cause issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem turned out to be bindings. I had this situation

`Bind<IMyDependency>().To<MyDependency>();`

and in the controller

`MyController(MyDependency dependency){}`

What i'm not sure about is how it worked at all after the first time but that was the actual problem.

Thanks nozzleman for pointing me towards it